# AttributeError: module 'keras.datasets.fashion_mnist' has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, keras

I have been trying to implement SVM on fashion mnist dataset using google colab and kept getting the error above. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Please do **not** use [a wall of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/) for an issue that can be perfectly described in a few lines - see how to create a [mcve] (edited); plus, this is clearly a `keras` question, and has nothing to do with `scikit-learn`, `svm`, or `google-colaboratory` (edited).

Answer (score 1):

To reshape your data, you should replace this part of your code:

```
data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
nsamples, nx, ny = data.shape
data = data.reshape(nsamples,nx*ny)
(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = data.load_data()
convert(xtrain, ytrain)
convert(xtest, ytest)
```

With this one:

```
(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()

# xtrain.shape = (60000,28,28) before reshaping
xtrain = xtrain.reshape(xtrain.shape[0],(xtrain.shape[1] * xtrain.shape[2]))
# xtrain.shape = (60000,784) after reshaping

# xtest.shape = (10000,28,28) before reshaping
xtest = xtest.reshape(xtest.shape[0],(xtest.shape[1] * xtest.shape[2]))
# xtest.shape = (10000,784) after reshaping

convert(xtrain, ytrain)
convert(xtest, ytest)
```

Comment: Will give an update as soon as it runs... even on google collab its taking time lol

Comment: This worked for me on google colab without any errors. But the execution took a bit of time...